# PHP mysql multiple row most recent result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table that look like this

[image]

I'm trying to create a mysql request that will give me, for a specific node, the last available value of each type ( and I have the list of type in another table ).

I really have no idea if its even possible or the right approach to do this kind of task,... i'm not an expert in mysql

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: I'm trying to obtain a table where i'll be able to reach each last value of a specific type like 'PH'

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use a correlated subquery in a `WHERE` clause.  I think you are asking for:

```
select d.*
from data d
where d.date = (select max(d2.date)
                from data d2
                where d2.node = d.node and d2.type = d.type
               );
```

Comment: As a note:  Under many circumstances, this will have better performance than the accepted answer in the "duplicate".